# How is the dot character represented within the bytes of a packet?

Tags: networking, byte, wireshark, packet

If we capture a DNS packet with wireshark, we can see among its bytes the domain name, in this case `tools.kali.org`:

[image: DNS packet]

The bytes in hexadecimal are `746f6f6c73046b616c69036f726700` and we can check with an ascii table how `74` corresponds to the character 't', `6f` to 'o' and so on. The problem comes when we arrive at the dot character, which should be represented in hexadecimal by `2e` and, however, is represented by `04` in the first appearance and `03` in the second appearance. 
Why does this happen and how does wireshark know that it has to represent a dot if they are different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dots are not represented. Dots are a textual representation, separating labels, so they don't appear in the packet.

> Each label is represented as a one octet length field followed by that
> number of octets.
>
> —IETF RFC 1035 [DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)

tools has 5 octets (bytes), kali has 4, org has 3. It's just happenstance that they are that sequence.